# C - In my book, it says arrays always use pass by reference. But the code that accompanies it doesn't make sense to me

Tags: c

```
int sum(int a[], int n)
{
    int i, s = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        s = s + a[i];
    return s;
}
```

I've learned that when passing by reference there are "*" next to the int on the functions header and there is also no return statement. But this code above which passes an array has no * and has a return statement. Can someone please tell when i am misunderstanding this.

Comment: This is because arrays and pointers are almost the same. Where you expect an array of some type, you can pass in a pointer of that same type. Here, it makes no difference if your function is `int sum(int *a, int n)` or `int sum(int a[], int n)`.

Comment: *a can be replaced with a[], but it has the potential to cause segmentation faults when you dont know it's size

Comment: Think about what an array is:  a contiguous block of memory on the stack.  So when you pass an array in, youre passing in the starting point of that contiguous block of memory.  

In your example, the starting point of the (a) array is passed in, along with the size of it (n).  (i) is a local variable declared to iterate through the array up to (n).  (s), the return variable is declared at 0, and will hold the sum of the array.

Finally, since youre returning (s), an int type, the function is declared as "int sum" to match the return type.

Comment: @wbt11a On The stack. Or on the heap. Or in the data segment. Or, ...

Comment: @HermanTorjussen: No, arrays and pointers are *not* almost the same. They are entirely distinct concepts. An array object contains a sequence elements of some type; a pointer object contains an address. See my answer.

Comment: As glglgl is pointing out ( I think ), in this instance the array is declared on the stack.

Comment: @wbt11a: In this case, yes (assuming that the implementation uses a "stack"), but your previous comment implies that all arrays are on the stack.

Comment: I'm certain this is a duplicate many times over, but I'm too lazy to track it down.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your book is misleading.  Arrays are not passed by reference; rather, arrays cannot be passed as arguments in function calls, or defined as parameters in function declarations, *at all*.

All parameters in C are passed by value (though you can simulate the effect of pass-by-reference by passing a pointer value).

There are two special-case rules at play here.

First, a parameter of array type is *adjusted* at compile time to a pointer to the array's element type. So this:

```
int sum(int a[], int n)
```

really means:

```
int sum(int *a, int n)
```

Second, an expression of array type, in most contexts, is implicitly converted to a pointer to the array's first element. The exceptions are:

- When the array expression is the operand of `sizeof` (`sizeof arr` yields the size of the array, not the size of a pointer);
- When the array expression is the operand of unary `&` (`&arr` yields the address of the entire array, not the address of a pointer); and
- When the array is a string literal in an initializer used to initialize an array object (`char s[] = "hello";` copies the string; it doesn't decay to a `char*` pointer).

In addition to that, the array indexing operator `[]` requires a *pointer* as one of its operands. `arr[i]` is, by definition, equivalent to `*(arr+i)`.

Some people, even some book authors, will tell you that arrays and pointers are really the same thing. They are not; they are entirely distinct concepts. It happens that the language rules are set up in such a way that (a) we manipulate pointers to refer to elements of arrays rather than manipulating arrays as a while, and (b) the language syntax (unfortunately) makes it easy to be confused.

Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) does a good job of explaining the relationship between arrays and pointers in C. Read it.

Comment: Saying that arrays and pointers are entirely different *concepts* is exaggerating your point a bit. In some contexts - like this - they  behave exactly the same. My point is that the `sum()` function doesn't need to know the difference.

Comment: @HermanTorjussen: No, it's not an exaggeration at all. Arrays and pointers are entirely different. The `sum` function does know the difference; its parameter is of pointer type, and it assumes that the pointer points to the first element of an array of at least `n` elements. The prefix of an indexing operator `x[y]` must be a pointer; the pointer can be the result of the implicit conversion of an array expression to pointer type. The relationship between arrays and pointers can be confusing, but the absolutely are different concepts.

Answer (score 2):

I think the first thing we need here is some clarification on parameter passing; because based on what you're saying, I'm under the impression your book is leading you astray.

---

**parameter passing in general:**

"passing by reference" doesn't exist in C. Using the star in the function parameter list is detonating something is a pointer. When you pass a pointer, then value that the pointer is pointing *at* can be updated.

ie:

```
void foo(int a){  // a is a local copy, the initial value is set by the calling
    a = 5;        // function, this assignment to 5 will have no effect outside of this
    return;       // scope
}
```

so this makes sense if you think about it called as:

```
foo(10);
```

Would it make sense that after this call `10` is now set to the value of `5`? No. `10` is still `10`.

When you pass a *pointer* to something, you adjust the value that is being pointed *at*, not the value of the pointer:

```
void foo(int *a){  // a is a local copy of the pointer, but it's pointing at whatever 
    *a = 5;        // the original pointer was, so adjustments here effect the original
    return;        // value
}
```

such that:

```
int z = 4;
foo(&z);
printf("%d\n", z); // 5 would now be printed
```

You also mentioned there would be no `return` statement. The `return` statement has nothing to do with what is being passed. If you pass a single pointer and all you're going to do is update the value it's pointing at then you don't ***need*** to return a value, but just because you're doing that doesn't mean you ***can't*** return a value. Frequently you'll see a function update the values of the parameter list, but it still returns a "0" (for success) or a "-1" (for failure) to let you know the outcome of the operation.

---

**Passing an array**

Now that the basics are out of the way, passing an array is a special case. When you write code using an array in the parameter list, as you did here:

```
int sum(int a[], int n)
```

The array is implicitly converted to a pointer of the array's type. So in this case it reads `int a[]` but it's compiled as `int *a`. When you use the array in the function:

```
a[i]
```

The compiler knows this is an int and it will take the address of `a` add to it `i*sizeof(int)` and dereference the result to give you the correct value stored in that location.

Answer (score 0):

In this case (but not always), `int a[]` is equivalent to `int *a`.

And, you *can* have a return statement when you pass some argument by reference. The type of the value that you return from the function has nothing to do with the type of the argument `a`: `sum()` is a function returning an integer, and `s` is the integer that you return.

Answer (score 0):

I have come accross books and teachers that say that arrays are always passed by reference, both are wrong. you dont actually pass arrays you pass pointers (the compiler switches [] with * at compile time) and in pointers case they are not pass by reference (as you would expect) what happens is that you can change the value of whatever it is the pointer points to and it will remain changed outside the function. But you cannot change what the pointer points to unless you pass it via reference. i.e

```
void do_something (int * &ptr);
```

Edit: Sample code and output for example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int x1 = 10;
int x2 = 20;
int x3 = 30;
int x4 = 40;
int x5 = 50;

void do_something(int * ptr)
{
    *ptr = x2;

    ptr = &x3;

}

void do_something_again(int * &ptr)
{
    *ptr = x4;

    ptr = &x5;

}


int main()
{
    int * ptr = &x1;
    cout << *ptr << endl;
    do_something(ptr);
    cout << *ptr << endl;
    do_something_again(ptr);
    cout << *ptr << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output as Expected is:
10 (x1)
20 (x2)
50 (x5)

Comment: Im passing it in a function... not declaring it... should have been more clear, my bad. check edited.

Comment: No, that's still a syntax error. If you want to update what a pointer is pointing to you need to pass a pointer to a pointer. `(int **ptr)`

Comment: actually you are wrong, I coded a sample and ran it to be sure.